# SQLite Android Update statement not changing the new column value

Tags: android, sqlite

sQLdB = openDb(sQLdB);

```
    sQLdB.rawQuery("UPDATE item_support_table SET groupname ='NANO' WHERE groupcode = 5",null ); 

    closedb(sQLdB);
```

The update query is not working no errors are thrown.The row with groupcode = '5' /groupcode = 5 is not updated with new value NANO whose columnName  groupname with new name NANO . Insert ,Select, delete all working fine Why is it happening is there any mistake

rowid  groupcode      groupname 
1         1            vegetables
2         2            grocery
5         5            Biscuits

Answer (score 0):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for queries that don't return data.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not execute it until one of the `moveTo..()` methods is called on the returned `Cursor`. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rawQuery()` when you execute a `SELECT` statement that returns rows from the table.
If you want to update a row the recommended way to do it is with the method `update()` with `ContenetValues` and `?` placeholders for the parameters of the `WHERE` clause:

```
ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
c.put("groupname", "NANO");
sQLdB.update("item_support_table", c, "groupcode = ?", new String[] {"5"});
```